# How to call an AngularJS scope-defined function from an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am defining a directive that builds a menu by interpreting a list of menu entries defined as objects in an array.

The menu opens and displays fine. It's a pop-over menu: it shows up in the foreground above whatever part of the page that it needs to cover. So far, so good.

However, I want to hide the menu as soon as the user clicks outside the menu. For that, I've used answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) to build this:

```
$scope.closeOnClick = function($scope) {
    var $menu = $('#menu-view');
    $(document).on('click', function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('#menu-view').length) {
            if ($menu.is(":visible")) {
                $scope.hideMenu();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`hideMenu` is a function defined in the controller of a toggle button that controls opening and closing the menu.

This `closeOnClick` function is defined in that very controller. It is also called there so as to "install" the click handler.

Unfortunately, it seems that the `$scope.hideMenu()` is ineffective and no errors are reported in the console. I have also tried using Angular events, with broadcast/on but to no avail.

I'm looking for ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical angular issue. The DOM event handler does NOT run within the Angular lifecycle, thats why you need to use `$scope.apply`. BTW you should use angular.element() instead of plain jquery.

```
if ($menu.is(":visible")) {
    $scope.apply($scope.hideMenu);
}
```

Comment: By removing the visibility test, I've established that `$scope.$apply` does the trick. But although the menu is visible and the selector is correct, `$menu.is(":visible")` was returning false, which I don't get... I've ended up using a opened/close boolean (which I was already keeping and using in the scope) to provide that information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see your hideMenu function, but I guess to make your code work you need add `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.hideMenu();`

But this is non-angular approach, better use something like:

```
<button ng-click="hideButton=true" ng-if="!hideButton">Button to hide</button>
```